# What does "asymptotically proportional" mean?

Tags: probability

I am reviewing a paper that uses the term "asymptotically proportional" in a definition of a PDF. Unfortunately I can't find what this term precisely means. Can anyone fill me in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = c \in (0, \infty) .
$$

Comment: Please, define `f(x)` and `g(x)` and `c`. Sole formula is bare.

Comment: They're functions.  $c$ is a constant.

Comment: What does this mean?